# Apache Camel: error when bean endpoint returns null

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to implement a service that searches for an item in external database and, if found, saves it in the local one.

I have following route:

```
from("direct:find-and-save")
    .to("bean:itemSearcher?method=searchFor(${header.brand}, ${header.model})")
    .to("bean:itemConverter")
    .to("bean:itemRepository?method=saveItem");
```

It works perfectly when `itemSearcher` finds the item. When `itemSearcher` does not find the item, it returns `null`. I expected that body of the message would be set to `null` but I got the following exception:

`org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache to the required type`

I have debugged Camel's code right after `itemSearcher` returns `null` and seen that `null` effectively got set as body of out-message of the current exchange and then the out-message became in-message for the next exchange. But somewhere body gets replaced with `InputStreamCache` anyway.

My question is: how can I configure Camel to preserve `null` value as a message body? If it is not possible, how do I go around giving that the beans should not have dependencies of Camel (i.e. cannot take `Exchange` instance as an argument).

Please point me if I'm missing something in documentation I've read:

- [Bean Integration](http://camel.apache.org/bean-integration.html)
- [Bean Component](http://camel.apache.org/bean.html)
- [Bean Binding](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html)

I use Camel v. 2.18.0

Comment: I really doubt Camel adds InputStreamCache by default as I have routes that return null in various steps of the flow and I use choice()/when() to determine the content of the body. You might want to add a condition after the itemConverter to check for a null body. And how does the code in your item converter bean look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Camel 2.18.0 has that kind of misbehavior.

I have updated version to 2.18.1 (didn't change any of my code) and now `null` body gets to the next endpoint as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are calling a method where camel had to convert to a particular type before calling the method.

And if the value is null it won't be able to assign a type.

can you try defaulting value like this ${header.brand:ABC}, ${header.model:ABC}

OR default to empty string ${header.brand:}, ${header.model:}

Comment: The question is not about header values. `searchFor(${header.brand}, ${header.model})` works fine. This very method may return `null` and exception happens after that.

Answer (score -1):

I guess exception happens when your null body needs to be converted to what

```
.to("bean:itemConverter")
```

expects to get.

Perhaps you need an additional processor between itemSearcher and itemConverter to handle null body.
At least for debugging purpose try to put one (which has Processor implementation) and see how body actually looks in Exchange.

BTW: I'm not sure why "the beans should not have dependencies of Camel" as long as they are Camel endpoints?

ADDED: maybe bean:itemConverter has to be able to accept Object as body and then decide what to do when body is not an instance of needed "item" class.

Comment: I did as you suggested. I added `.process(exchange -> LOGGER.debug("body is {}", exchange.getIn().getBody()))` before `.to("bean:itemConverter")`. In the log I get `body is org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@28f67f4f`

Comment: The beans should be independent of Camel because those are used as direct dependencies in other parts of the application. I would write some wrappers only if there is no other way because now it seems it should work as it is.

Comment: That is expected... so there are 3 ways - 1. special processor in between, 2. itemConverter must accept Object and handle wrong type of body 3. as suggested by Rajesh special converter which will do the same - handle wrong type of body...

Comment: Could you please give me a refference to a document which sais that `null` body is supposed to be represented as `InputStreamCache` object in the next exchange?

Comment: ... still wondering how do you implement Camel Endpoint without dependency on Camel?

Comment: Not inside the beans.

Comment: About body: behind the scene Body in Camel is not actual object, but can be 0 element in array of objects. So, maybe because of message format there is an InputStream as another part of message... Some time back I had a problem with webservice InOut parameters in Camel and had to make an special interceptor  to avoid bug in Camel-CXF to handle it properly. It was also about that array of objects in body... and it was not documented. I had to travel through debugger...

Comment: Also it is not good anyway to use null as "valid body" - simple: when itemSearcher cannot find a type make it something and handle that "something" in itemConverter.

Answer (score -1):

It is excepted behavior according to camel document in  http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/type-converter.html

Could you try writing your own converter to do a null check? For Eg. 
context.getTypeConverterRegistry().addTypeConverter(MyOrder.class, String.class, new MyOrderTypeConverter());

Check the above document for more details.

Comment: It is expected behavior when there is no converter that can convert a message body from one type to another. And I don't have one. But I don't ever expect that `null` body all of a sudden become `InputStreamCache` instance. So my issue is not in conversion, it is unexpected object in the message body.